# how to solve this: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'B-A-BRS01' after importing data from a CSV file

Tags: python, django, sqlite

to be extremely brief, I have a model called `drilling`, it contains 4 foreign key from 4 other model tables. when I imported data from a `csv` file to my `drilling` table using DB Browser for `SQLite`, the import is successful. when I now go to the `drilling.html` page, I am unable to load it. this is the error:

```
ValueError at /project/
  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'B-A-BRS01'
```

And they redirect me to where the error occurred:

```
104 <td>{{ drilling.project_name }}</td> (that is in the drilling.html line 104)
```

this is a portion of my `drilling` model:

```
project_name = models.ForeignKey(Project)
drill_date = models.DateField(default= '2000-01-01')
shift = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = DRILLING_SHIFT)
holes_drilled = models.IntegerField(blank = False, null = True)
meters_drilled = models.DecimalField(blank = False, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null = True)
avgdepth_drilled = models.DecimalField(blank = True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null = True)
targetmeters_drilled = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = TARGET_MET)
comment = models.CharField(max_length = 220, blank = True, null = True)
geologist = models.ForeignKey(Personel, related_name='Geologist')
driller = models.ForeignKey(Personel, related_name='Driller')
auger = models.ForeignKey(Auger)
client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
```

portion of personel model (one of the foreign keys field of drilling):

```
class Personel(models.Model):
personel_full_name = models.CharField(max_length = 220, blank = False, null = False)
personel_designation = models.CharField(max_length = 200, choices = DESIGNATION, default=DESIGNATION[0][0])
personel_email = models.CharField(max_length = 220, blank = True, null = True)
personel_contact = models.CharField(max_length = 220, blank = True, null = True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.personel_full_name
    # +" ("+self.personel_designation+")"
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id, self.personel_full_name
    # +" : "+self.personel_designation
```

portion of drilling.html:

```
<tbody>
            {% for drilling in drillings %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.project_name}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.drill_date}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.shift}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.holes_drilled}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.meters_drilled}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.avgdepth_drilled}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.targetmeters_drilled}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.comment}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.geologist}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.driller}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.auger}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.client}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">{{ drilling.vehicle}}</a></td>
```

I would like to also add or remind that in the Db browser when the foreign heys fields are stored in integers fields and their names are also changed by adding `_id`: for instance if I named the field of the foreign key as `project_name` the DB will make it `project_name_id` and store the id of that very record instead of the value specified in the model.

please any help would be gladly accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you had a field which was a CharField, and now you're trying to convert it into a ForeignKey... That field already has data as String whereas the ForeignKey needs an Integer, that's why you got this `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'B-A-BRS01'`

Comment: i see. thank you but can you be specific on what can be done to solve it. i actually do not want to change my Charfield datatype in my other tables. is there other solution to this issue? thank you

Comment: The faster way is in case you don't have sensitive data is: remove that field, run `makemigrations & migrate`, then re-add the field, `makemigrations & migrate`

Comment: ok thanks a lot. i think from what you suggested i had another solution that pupped up: i actually put in those foreign key fields the id of the corresponding record from its main table. and when i import i do not get the error again. i get the page with the exact value i want. thank you.